# How can I package a xaml template into a nuget package for other developers to reuse?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nuget, wpf-controls

I have created a nuget out of some reusable code and frameworks that I have created for other developers to leverage and develop solutions faster. The nuget is hosted on our private nuget feed. Our application is a WPF application with clickonce deployment strategy. Now I would like to give the developers the mainwindow.xaml that I use as a template so that I can create a standardization. Is there any way I can package the mainwindow.xaml as a reusable template in the same nuget package that I have hosted in my private feed or atleast can I create a new nuget and host it for the same purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can place the `MainWindow.xaml` and `MainWindow.cs` files in the `content` directory of your NuGet package, and create an `Init.ps1` PowerShell script to move those files into the project.

The script’s parameters are:

`param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)`

There is some good information about adding files to the content directory at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec